# value of SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT allcolumns) bigger than SELECT COUNT(1)

Tags: mysql

I run the following SQL in MySQL, and why two `COUNT` show different results?

```
SELECT COUNT(1), COUNT(DISTINCT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) AS distinctCount FROM `parts_color`;
```

The results are:

- `COUNT(1)`: 647611
- `distinctCount`: 647263

Why?

Comment: `SELECT count(1)`  is the same as `SELECT(*)` and it will include NULL values, while count(col) will not include NULL values

Comment: The second value is smaller than the first

Answer (score 0):

Your table parts_color must have duplicate values.

SELECT COUNT(1) is similar to SELECT COUNT(*) which retains all the duplicate values and returns the count.

when you use DISTINCT in your query the duplicate values are discarded and hence the value is less the count(1).

Comment: But I run the  "create table xxx select distinct column1...column5 from parts_color".....it shows the same result as the table parts_color

Answer (score 0):

```
count(DISTINCT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
```

Above will only apply DISTINCT with column1, it will not check for DISTINCT for all other columns (column2, column3, column4, column5),
For COUNT() we need only one column, so use

```
COUNT(DISTINCT column1)
```

Comment: column1, column2
1,    2   
1,    3
the result of "select count(distinct column1,column2) " is 2

Comment: @Tanmay thats not the solution to the question asked by OP

Answer (score 0):

You have used distinct keyword with second count so it eliminates duplicate values.

And according to your results it seems that you have duplicate values so count(1) counts all NOT NULL values in column 1 and your second count eliminates duplicate values.

Comment: But I run the "create table xxx select distinct column1...column5 from parts_color".....it shows the same result as the table parts_color